# How to display one section using the title of the section while also using Core Data?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

I am using Core Data and want to display only one section of an array by passing from a previous View Controller the string of one of the section titles.  I am also using Core Data, so I am trying to figure out how I can set the section by the string, and then show the objects for that section.

I have tried the following:

First, I put the section title in a segue entitled selectedSection.

Then I put the numberOfSections as 1, since there will only be 1.

Then I set the titleForHeaderInSection as return selectedString.

Where it all goes wrong is in numberOfRowsInSection.  I can't figure out how to set the section to be selectedString.  I'll post the code I've tried below.

```
// From Previous View Controller
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) 
{
    if segue.identifier == "ShowSection" {
        let controller = segue.destination as! SectionsViewController
        controller.context = context

        let button = sender as! UIButton
        let section = photos[button.tag].place
        controller.selectedSection = section!
           // This passes on a String
    }
}

// Saving pins to the map 
if let annotationView = annotationView {
        annotationView.annotation = annotation        
        let button = annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView as! 
        if let index = photos.firstIndex(of: annotation as! Photo) {
            button.tag = index
}

// In the Sections View Controller (i.e. the second VC)
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if let sections = fetchedRC.sections {
            let currentSection = sections[section]
            return currentSection.numberOfObjects
        } else {
            return 0
        }
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
     return selectedSection
}
```

Any idea how I can set the section as selectedSection and show the objects for that selectedSection? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, if you want to display only the section of the selected row in the previous screen, why don't you just pass the array of rows in the section in the previous screen? and this way, your "new screen" will be only a tableview with one section, and rows for that section, is this correct? or I misunderstood

Comment: Thanks.  What would the code be for the array of rows? Something like fetchedRC.sections?  I think you actually may be correct.  If needed I’ll post more code.  T

Comment: what’s the structure of the data source of your first view controller? Can you post it plz

Comment: Hello, thanks for hanging in there with me.  I'm tinkering with the code, and I think you are on to something.  I forgot that the first view controller is a map that stores pins on a map and annotations.  I posted some of the code above.

Comment: ok so once you click on a pin you move to the next viewcontroller that has the tableview?? but when you fill the map, you Don't have the information of the business that you want to show right?

Comment: Correct.  That’s stored in Core Data, at least I think (new guy alert!).

Comment: How does the ferchedrc.sections response looks like? Wouldn’t be easier for you just to fetch the section that you need? Create a query just for that section by an ID or something like that?

Comment: Hi Mike.  Here's where I'm at.  I believe that I need to pass on a type of NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo.  In my code, that generally looks like:
    fetchedRC.sections![section] In this case, I just can't figure out what the section should be.  I tried putting in 0, but received the error that they found nil for a non-optional.  Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: a section is information about a pin right? I assume that you have stored each pin information on the database, that info, must have an ID, so, search by ID in your core data, and change the way you fill your table view based on that particular pin info... I’m sorry but without seeing the complete implementation, I’m just guessing here